# What is the syntax for click events in React Hooks for passing arguments

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

This always worked great for me in React class components:

```
let myValue: string = "Hello World";
<Button onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this, myValue)}></Button>
```

I found this syntax in the React Hooks documentation and I like it, but it does not always pass back a value:

```
<Button onClick={handleClick} value={myValue}></Button>
```

This syntax works, but is hard to type and looks messy:

```
<Button onClick={() => handleClick(myValue)}></Button>
```

This is yet another way that works with hooks, but seems hacky to me.

```
  <Button onClick={handleClick.bind(null, myValue)}></Button>
```

I'm confused by too many choices.  Is there not just some best practice way of doing this?

Comment: 1. lambda expression in an event function is not recommended. 2. where the `myValue` is coming from that you want to pass it as function param? if it is from state way do you want to use it as a param?

Comment: The question lacks the context, it doesn't mention where myValue comes from.

Comment: @estus - I added some code to clarify where myValue comes from.

Comment: @Lambert I see, I updated the answer to cover this.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is perfectly suitable way to do this:

```
<Button onClick={() => handleClick(myValue)}></Button>
```

The only downside is that `onClick` prop has new value on each render and triggers a re-render of child component - even if it's pure. This may or may not cause performance problems depending on specific component; this will be a problem if there are many `Button` instances or their re-renders are expensive.

If a value is static, a callback can be defined as constant function outside a component:

```
// outside function component
const myValue = "Hello World";
const myHandleClick = () => handleClick(myValue);
...
// inside function component
<Button onClick={myHandleClick}></Button>
```

If a value is dynamic and is available only inside a component, a function can be defined inside a component and memoized with `useMemo` or `useCallback` hook (as another answer already mentions):

```
// inside function component
const myHandleClick = useCallback(() => handleClick(myValue), [myValue]);
...
<Button onClick={myHandleClick}></Button>
```

Answer (score 6):

The first and last versions in your question both create a new function, so if you can get away with just giving the function `handleClick` to a prop, you should do that.

If you need to pass arguments to the function you can still use your first version in function components, but since `this` is not used, you can just set it to `null`.

```
<Button onClick={handleClick.bind(null, myValue)}></Button>
```

Comment: Is this how you do it in a hooks component and is what you recommend?

Comment: If I have to create a new function to pass some argument I personally use `() => handleClick(myValue)`, but the differences between the two approaches are negligible. It's primarily a matter of taste.

Comment: @Thule - But whats this talk from Amir about "lambda expression in an event function is not recommended"  Doesn't your personal choice do that?

Comment: @Lambert I don't agree with "lambda expression in an event function is not recommended". I don't see why that should be the case.

Comment: this is easier and nice approach

Comment: Thanks, my scenario works using this technique as well: In my case I just wanted to pass the object to the function so I can access its data.
`const columns = React.useMemo(
    () => [
    {
Header: 'Content List',
        columns: [
          {
           Header: 'Title / Filename',
           accessor: 'content_title_filename',
            Cell: ({row})=> <a href={row.original.content_url} onClick={AccessResource.bind(row,null)}>{row.values.content_title_filename}</a>
}, ..

function AccessResource()
{
  alert('passed the name ->' + this.original.content_title_filename);

}`